# Reformatting some mailing lists depending on an excel file

Tags: python, excel, email

I want to modify a bunch of mailing lists. Each mailing list contains a list of email addresses (one per line), that I call “old” adresses. For a given email address the old one is referenced in an .xlsx file together with the new one. If the old address is not referenced, it means it is obsolete and must be removed. Sometimes the email address in a mailing list is already the good one. In this case it must be kept unmodified.

I did it in python. I don’t really have a problem but I realized it was not so obvious so I wanted to share my work. First because it looks like some posts I have already seen and it may be helpful; second, because my code is absolutely not optimized (I didn’t need to optimize it as it takes ~0.5s like this in my case) and **I would be curious to see what you would do to optimize my code in case of 10^8 mailing lists.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the python code I eventually implemented:

```
import xlrd
import os
path_old = 'toto'
path_new = 'tata'
mailing_lists = os.listdir(path_old)
good_domain = 'gooddomain.fr'
printing_level = 3

# reading of the excel file
xlsfilename = 'adresses.xlsx'
xlsfile = xlrd.open_workbook(xlsfilename)
number_of_persons = 250
number_column_old_mail = 7
number_column_new_mail = 5
newmail = []
oldmail = []
for count in range(number_of_persons):
    oldmail.append(xlsfile.sheets()[0].cell(count,number_column_old_mail).value)
    newmail.append(xlsfile.sheets()[0].cell(count,number_column_new_mail).value)
############

for mailinglist_name in mailing_lists:
    if printing_level > 0:
        print('* dealing with mailing list ',mailinglist_name)
    new_mailinglist = []
    new_name = mailinglist_name + '_new'

    with open(path_old+'/'+mailinglist_name,'r') as inputfile:
        for line in inputfile:
            if len(line)<2: # to ignore blank lines. This length of 2 is completly arbitrary
                continue
            line = line.rstrip('\n')
            ok = False

# case 1: the address inside the old mailing list is ok ==> copied in the new mailing list
            if '@' in line:
                if line[line.index('@')+1:] == good_domain:
                    new_mailinglist.append(line)
                    if printing_level > 1:
                        print(' --> address ',line,' already ok ==> kept unmodified')
                    ok = True

# case 2: the address inside the old mailing list is not ok ==> must be treated
            if not ok:
                if printing_level > 1:
                        print(' --> old address ',line,' must be treated')
                try:
# case 2a: the old address is in the excel file ==> replaced
                    ind = oldmail.index(line)
                    if printing_level > 2:
                        print('  --> old address found in the excel file and replaced by ',newmail[ind])
                    new_mailinglist.append(newmail[ind])
                except ValueError:
# case 2b: the old address is obsolete ==> removed
                    if printing_level > 2:
                        print('  --> old address removed')

    with open(path_new+'/'+new_name,'w') as outputfile:
        for address in new_mailinglist:
            outputfile.write(address+'\n')
```